# Can I use OpenMP derectives inside functions called during parallel execution?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

If I have the following code snippet, for example:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    ...do stuff...
    foo()
    ...do more stuff...
}
```

and inside `foo()` I have

```
void foo()
{
    ...do stuff...
    #pragma omp barrier
    ...do more stuff...
}
```

will the barrier work as intended, ie, will the various threads pause execution properly and wait for other threads to arrive at that point in `foo()`?

Comment: Yes, they will unless in the ...do stuff... does something that would make some of the thread not execution foo(). As long as all the created threads call the foo() and reach the barrier the code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, it was unclear to me how `barrier` works in the context of functions called privately in different threads, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Such directives/constructs are called _orphaned_ and they work when in the dynamic scope of a parallel region, i.e. when they are encountered as part of the code executed between the entry into and the exit from a parallel region.